# Reselect multiple instance memoization

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I using React/Redux/Reselect.

From the [reselect doc](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#sharing-selectors-with-props-across-multiple-component-instances), if I have multiple component that will use the selector with different parameters, I need to create one per instance.

```
const makeGetVisibleTodos = () => {
  return createSelector(
    [ 
       (state, props) => props.visibilityFilter, 
       state => state.todos,
    ],
    (visibilityFilter, todos) => {
       return todos.filter(td => td.visibility === visibilityFilter)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

But in my case, the `listId` can come from several origins (Eg. `props.listId`, `props.location.match.listId`, `props.location.search.listId` etc.)

So I feel more like writing the following:

```
const makeGetVisibleTodos = listId => {
  return createSelector(
    [
      state => state.todos,
    ],
    (todos) => {
       todos.filter(td => td.listId === listId)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

and connect it the following way:

```
  connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
      offerer: makeGetVisibleTodos(ownProps.location.match.listId)(state, ownProps),
    }),
  )
```

I'm pretty sure it works, but I'm not 100% sure this will memoize correctly:

If two components call `makeGetVisibleTodos` with the same `listId`, they will have 2 different cache values, right? Which is not what I want ...

How about this?

```
const makeGetVisibleTodos = listId => {
  return createSelector(
    state => state.todos,
    state => listId,
    (todos, listId) => {
       todos.filter(td => td.listId === listId)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

In this case, do `makeGetVisibleTodos(ownProps.listId)` and `makeGetVisibleTodos(ownProps.match.params.listId)` share the same cache value, when `ownProps.listId === ownProps.match.params.listId`?

Or another way to formulate the question is: how to pass extra-parameters that wouldn't (directly) depend on `state` and `ownProps` but are checked on equality during memoization?

I could also extend `ownProps`:

```
  connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
      offerer: makeGetVisibleTodos()(state, Object.assign({}, ownProps, {listId: ownProps.location.match.listId}),
    }),
  )
```

But find it super ugly and it's loosing the point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you posted above, memoization will not work correctly because you create a new instance of the reselect selector everytime the `mapStateToProps` function is called.

Notice how in the docs the `mapStateToProps` function also becomes a factory function (`makeMapStateToProps`) and the `makeGetVisibleTodos` is called before returning the actual `mapStateToProps` function, like so.

```
const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const getVisibleTodos = makeGetVisibleTodos()
  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
      todos: getVisibleTodos(state, props)
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}
```

Also, you do not pass the props that you use in your selector in the `makeGetVisibleTodos()` call, but when actually calling the selector itself.

This would result in something like

```
const makeGetVisibleTodos = () => {
  return createSelector(
    state => state.todos,
    state => (_, listId), // Here you have access to all the arguments passed
    (todos, listId) => {
       todos.filter(td => td.listId === listId)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Then you can write the selectors like this:

```
const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const getVisibleTodos = makeGetVisibleTodos()
  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {

    return {
      todos: getVisibleTodos(state, props.params.match.listId),
      todos2: getVisibleTodos(state, props.listId),
      todos3: getVisibleTodos(state, 'hardcodedListId')
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}
```

Comment: Nice. I think I get it (though I'm still unclear about *when* I need to use the factory function, if `createSelector` makes a purely functional function). I think there is a fix in the second line of `makeGetVisibleTodos`: `state => (_, listId)` should be `(state, listId) => listId`, shouldn't it?

Comment: You are right that `state` would be the first argument of the second line, but because `state` is not used in the function itself I wrote an underscore to indicate it goes unused.

I think making use of the factory function is good if you have a `connect`ed component that is rendered in multiple instances and is prone to a lot of rerendering :)

Comment: It's also worth checking out the PR the pull request where this was implemented in Redux! The explanation of how it works is really good https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/pull/348

Answer (score 2):

As the author of [re-reselect](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect) (a small wrapper around `reselect`) I'd like to point out how the library would solve your use case.

`re-reselect` provides selectors which retains **memoization across different components** out of the box.

```
import createCachedSelector from 're-reselect';

const getVisibleTodos = createCachedSelector(
  state => state.todos,
  (state, listId) => listId,
  (todos, listId) => {
     todos.filter(td => td.listId === listId)
    }
  }
)(
  (todos, listId) => listId, // Create/use a different selector for each different listId
);
```

Use it like a normal selector (in any different container component) and forget about selectors factories:

```
const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
      todos: getVisibleTodos(state, props.params.match.listId),
      todos2: getVisibleTodos(state, props.listId),
      todos3: getVisibleTodos(state, 'hardcodedListId')
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}
```

This use case is also described in [re-reselect docs](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect/blob/master/examples/2-avoid-selector-factories.md).

Comment: I can't make your answer the officially accepted one since it has dependencies, but THANKS! I wanted to open an issue in `reselect` suggesting exactly what `re-reselect` does: varying the cache size upon different parameters values, not instanciations. Have you been suggesting to make this default to `reselect`? I can't see any tradeoff in using your version instead of `reselect`.

Comment: `re-reselect` adds a little logic/function calls around `reselect`, therefore using `reselect` directly is the best option from the point of view of performance when no factory/cache management is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will not do memoization correctly since when you call `makeGetVisibleTodos` is always creating a new selector. You can improve on it by writing

```
const listIdQuerySelector = (state, props) => {
    return props.match.params && props.match.params.listId;
};
const todoSelector = createSelector(
    [
      listIdQuerySelector,
      state => state.todos,
    ],
    (listId, todos) => {
       todos.filter(td => td.listId === listId)
      }
    }
  )
```

and use it like

```
connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
      offerer: makeGetVisibleTodos(state, ownProps),
    }),
  )
```